# Debugging Framework Code in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, symbol-server

Is this post (http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) still the preferred method for debugging framework code from visual studio?  Or has anything changed?

Comment: The article you posted is exactly how I debug framework source.

Comment: This does not work for me now. I am able to debug .NET 4.0 source code, but not .NET 3.5 SP1 source code. And in order to do so, I download .NET 4.0 symbols and source code from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx and point my Tools->Options->Debugging options to point at the symbols from that install (which install to a location on my local hard drive ... I am not pointing it at Microsoft's symbol servers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 2008, the answers to your question are yes and no, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way. The other way is using the upcoming [.NET Reflector Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) that allows decompiling the framework and debugging through it. A free beta is available.

The first way has the advantage that you get the actual source code with comments. The second way has the advantage that you can debug framework code even if Microsoft does not provide the source for the part you are interested in.